# How do I show a field if it contains content, but hide it if it's empty?

Tags: ee2

I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" status="open"}

<ul class="arrow-side-2">
<li><h4>Properties</h4></li>
</ul>
    <p>{properties}</p>

<ul class="arrow-side-2">
<li><h4>Applications</h4></li>
</ul>
    <p>{applications}</p>

<ul class="arrow-side-2">
<li><h4>Production</h4></li>
</ul>
        <p>{production}</p>

<ul class="arrow-side-2">
<li><h4>Packaging</h4></li>
</ul>
    <p>{packaging}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

How do I hide:

```
<ul class="arrow-side-2">
<li><h4>Production</h4></li>
</ul>
        <p>{production}</p>
```

If there is nothing in the {production} field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Or, you can just do:

```
{if production}<p>{production}</p>{/if}
```

Comment: Derek, thanks for fixing my code. I couldn't figure out how to display the code as `code` the proper way.

Comment: I wanted to hide the whole thing so I put {if production} above <ul class="arrow-side-2"> That worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Not sure how I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if production != ""}
    <p>{production}</p>
{/if}
```